# Angular HttpClient.get demorando

Tags: angular, get, httpclient

Boa tarde galerinha, seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um projeto do meu curso com umas pessoas, mas tem um trecho onde estou sofrendo um pouco pelo motivo de que o código manda a requisição pro meu back (Em Java) e já continua executando o resto na hora, isso ta dando problema pra mim fazer a verificação que preciso...
Estou tentando fazer uma verificação de login existente, onde claro, não podem haver dois logins iguais

```js
export interface existeUsuario {
   usuarioExistente: boolean;
}
```

```js
verificaUsuarioExistente(login: string): boolean {
   console.log(login); // Aparece no console o login digitado
   var existe: boolean;
                // Usando uma interface pois foi a única forma de conseguir puxar o back-end, se tiver algumas forma de usar somente um .get<boolean> me falem por favor
   this.http.get<existeUsuario>(this.urlApi + 'verificaUser&login=' + login).subscribe(retorno => {
      console.log(retorno); // Log: {usuarioExistente: true}
      existe = retorno.usuarioExistente;
      console.log('Retorno 1' + existe);
   }
   console.log('Retorno 2: ' + existe);
   return existe;
}

cadastrarUsuario(login: string, senha: string, email: string) {
   if(login!= '' && senha != '' && email != '') {
      if(this.usuarioExistente(login) === true) {
        console.log('Usuario já existe');
      } else {
        console.log('Usuario não existe');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Informações em Branco!');
    }
  }
```

[image]

Como podem ver, o Retorno 2 está vindo antes do Retorno 1, o que acaba retornando undefined pois não foi definido no .get ainda, ai depois ele define (sempre como true no momente pois coloquei um login já existente no meu banco de dados)

Comment: Qual **Retorno 2**?

Comment: Opa @LeAndrade , tinha esquecido de colocar no código o número, mas o Retorno 2 é só para teste da variável mesmo, porém em vez de estar retornando undefined deveria estar retornando true igualmente o primeiro

Comment: **NÃO**, não deveria não, pq o `console.log('Retorno 2: ' + existe);` já é processado assim que a função é executada, e como a variável não possui valor ela retorna **`undefined`**!!

Comment: @LeAndrade exatamente! Eu queria saber de uma forma em que essa parte fosse processada somente após a variável ter o valor definido, ou seja, depois do .get ter a resposta dele

Comment: O retorno de um **http** é `assíncrono`, ou seja, pode retornar rápido, demorar ou até mesmo nem retornar, vc só obterá o retorno dentro do **subscribe**.

Comment: Ok... E não tem alguma forma de eu conseguir fazer o código esperar a resposta vir, pra somente dai fazer meu `if(usuaroExistente == true)`?

Comment: Cara se fosse eu não faria a função `verificaUsuarioExistente()`, só faria a **`cadastrarUsuario()`** e ali validaria se o usuário já existe!

Comment: Hmm, e nesse caso seria so colocar o .get dentro da condição do if?

Comment: Isso, exatamente!